# Programatically find shortcuts to my app

Tags: windows

So, my patience with antiviruses and general securities is over and, like Google Chrome and some other smart guys I will put my executables inside Application Data, so I can update my app more freely, not needing admin priviledges and so on.

Well, one problem I´ll have is, as usual, legacy. I want to make all the installed copies of my software to be moved to the AppData area.

My question is, is there any way for me to find and dele or edit all shortcuts to my executable programatically?

Comment: Why would you not just update your main executable, and leave it in the same place all the time?

Comment: You should only change or delete the shortcuts your application or installer created itself.  For one thing, given an arbitrary shortcut, there's no really reliable way for you to tell which user is going to be using it, so how would you know which application data folder to point it at?